# Add headers in a Flask app with unicode_literals

Tags: python, unicode, nginx, flask

Adding headers with unicode_literals enabled seems to fail with Nginx, uWSGI and a simple Flask app:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from flask import Flask, make_response

app = Flask('test')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    response = make_response()
    response.status_code = 401
    response.headers = {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="test"'} # Fail
    # response.headers = {b'WWW-Authenticate': b'Basic realm="test"'} # Succeed
    return response

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The app is available directly for debug purpose or through Nginx -> uWSGI -> Flask and works well.

- When I use a browser to connect directly to the app, I've got a login dialog and the
  `WWW-Authenticate` header is correct.
- The same request going through Nginx returns a header `Transfert-Encoding: chunked` and
  discard the `WWW-Authenticate` header.

Forcing bytestring (`b'...') format to add the header make the app works as expected in both cases.
The file is encoded in UTF-8 and there's a`coding` declaration for the Python interpreter.
We're using Python 2.7.3, Nginx 1.4.2 and uWSGI 1.3.

Is there any known incompatibility between Nginx or uWSGI, Flask and unicode_literals?
Thanks!

edit:
The problem seems to come from uWSGI (
https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/plugins/python/wsgi_headers.c#L116), since it only checks for PyString and not PyUnicode for Python2, if I understand this code correctly.

edit:
Armin Ronacher has fixed a similar bug (https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/758) 5 months ago, but I didn't find the commit in werkzeug git log yet. I don't know if the fix is scoped to the `redirect()` function or more broadly on headers handling. I'm using Werkzeug 0.9.4 and Flask 0.10.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is indeed due to a bug in **Werkzeug**. As you noticed, this is now corrected since Jun 4, 2013 (cf. the [related commit](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/commit/f3435a346d0d559d1c19bbfca3745476c4942124) on Github). You can have a bug free version of Werkzeug by using the version **0.9.5** instead of the **0.9.4**.

Moreover, to troubleshoot your problem, I added `app.debug = True` just after the initialization of your Flask application. This allows me to got the following error in uWSGI logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/afigura/.virtualenvs/stack-python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/afigura/.virtualenvs/stack-python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in wsgi_app
    return response(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/afigura/.virtualenvs/stack-python2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 1201, in __call__
    start_response(status, headers)
TypeError: http header key must be a string
```

This corresponds to the error mentioned in [the bug you found](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/758) on Github.

So, you can use the following workaround to get **Flask/Werkzeug** working with `unicode_literals`:

```
response.headers = {b'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="test"'}
```

Or:

```
response.headers = {str('WWW-Authenticate'): 'Basic realm="test"'}
```

But I recommend to simply update your Werkzeug version to >=0.9.5 if you can.

Also, please note that although the `headers` attribute of a Flask/Werkzeug response behaves like a dictionary, it is in fact a `Headers` object (see [Werkzeug source code](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/wrappers.py#L755)). Hence, I advise you to use it as follows:

```
response.headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Basic realm="test"'
```

You can see some examples about this on the [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.make_response) of the function `make_response`.

Comment: @Nicolas: I had not seen the date of your question. Since then, I hope that you found a solution :)

Comment: Yep, we used a bitstring cast to circumvent the problem back when we got the problem. Thanks for your very clear response, though, and for pointing the difference between the Dict and Headers object.